# Getting the offset of the RenderTransformOrigin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, zooming, rendertransform

I'm currently using the RenderTransformOrigin to zoom in on a point. According to [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) it offsets it too, this causes some problems for some calculation I make. So is there anyway to get the offset of the RenderTransformOrigin?